# Dynamic fields/properties in Doctrine2 - how?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I I would like plugins to be able to add properties to my models. For example, I have a model "Message". A "Like" plugin can add property "likedtimes" to it and maintain it. How can I get such functionality?

One solution is to create a separate table and model for likes. But that would require a join or additional select whenever likes are to be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to replicate common functionality between **Entities** (not models)?

If so, I would recommend you implement your own [behavior](https://github.com/everzet/DoctrineExtensions), using the built-in event system.

FYI: [Difference between entities and models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029952/ddd-and-mvc-difference-between-model-and-entity)

Comment: I am trying to allow third-party programmer to write plugins for my web application. I need to provide him a way to add properties to my entities.

Comment: I've looked into this before when I was trying to make my own behavior system. I couldn't bake in a way to dynamically add a column. You can't just modify the ClassMetadata because the entity physically needs the property.

Comment: If you're interested, the best alternative I found was an EventListener that checked interfaces that the entity implemented and made sure the entity had certain properties based on that interface; if it didn't an exception was thrown.