# Storing dynamic fields with Doctrine2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

in our app, we are looking to use doctrine2, however, there is one feature we want to offer but am completely confused as to how it would work.

we want our customers to be able to define custom fields to our standard objects.  so, these fields would be made on-the-fly, and not part of the object definition that is known and mapped by doctrine.

our first thought was to use nosql (mongodb or amazon dynamodb) to store some of this data, but since we want to use doctrine to handle our core objects, we would like to stay within the realm of doctrine to achieve this without have to extend beyond it to store this data.

one thing on my mind was using doctrine's ability to serialize/unserialize complex objects and just have like a hash of custom field names and their values as an extra property in the object, however, this would not allow us to have a feature that would search these fields if we ever wanted to allow that...

anyone ever attempted to do this with doctrine2 or any orm variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using Doctrine ODM, which is Doctrine 2 but for NoSQL - I believe they support at least MongoDB.

Another approach would be to use serialization as you said. You probably shouldn't worry about search too much - I would recommend to use a separate fulltext search engine (Solr, ElasticSearch, or other) as they provide much more versatility and performance for search vs SQL fulltext search.

Third, you could use Doctrine alongside with NoSQL. In this case, you probably should abstract your querying into a service class or such, so that you can use Doctrine to query for the data from your SQL DB, and some other to query the remaining data.

Finally, you could consider using a key-value table. One column represents the key, another the value.

Comment: we haven't fully implemented any of these just yet, but they all seem like legit ways of dealing with the problem, thanks!