# MVC Mayhem; Sorting out Model responsibility and structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

My understanding of MVC-type architectures over the last few weeks/months has advanced (I'd say) considerably, and I owe most of my thanks to fellow SO enthusiasts; so, thank you!

I'm still challenged by something though, the `Model`. So far I've sorted out and created;

- A simple `Request` object, that consolidates request data (GET/POST/etc. params, HTTP headers, etc.)
- A simple `Response` object, that collects response data (HTML, JSON, HTTP headers, etc.)
- A fancy `Router` that resolves URIs against a regex-powered routing table, validates them based on `Controller` file/class existence/inheritance, and updates the `Request` object with any supplementary parameters.
- A simple `Dispatcher` object that sets up the working environment, creates and initializes the necessary `Controller`, and sends it a `Request` and `Response` object to work with.

**Now the `Model`.**

I understand that in many (some) circumstances the `Model` is merely representational of it's associated entity, the table, with CRUD methods (*`addUser()`, `deleteUser()`, etc.*) In others there are further levels of abstraction, preventing controllers from accessing finer-grain CRUD functionality, consolidating methods (*`replaceUser()` - deletes, adds, then returns user data*)

I'm wondering what my best course of action is; for a few specific reasons.

I've created a `Gateway` class that acts as a proxy to an intended `Model`, performing ACL checks (*using the `Acl` object, a special case "`Model`"*) using the `Request` and desired method and arguments as parameters for the check. The `Controller` is responsible for determining the outcome of a failed ACL check (display all but that data, redirect, etc.)

I've also introduced an (*and I've referred to it as hybrid REST/RPC previously, but I believe that's incorrect as my resource URI architecture is out-the-window*) RPC API layer. An API call consists of a method, arguments, and request parameters, is managed by the special `ApiController` and is fed like a normal `Model` call to the `Gateway`.

It seems to me like the best way to facilitate data access, would be a (*uh-oh*) single enormous model object, disregarding any ORM, that maintains all database interaction methods, proving simplicity for managing the Gateway/ACL/Model relationship. **No, that sounds wrong.**

**Given these architectural choices, what may be my best choice for modeling my, um..  `Model`? Have I really thrown caution and best-practice to the wind with the aforementioned design choices?**

Comment: The model should only act as a proxy to your data provider, and should only be accessed by a controller or the view, if any of these are false then you should restructure your code so that it fits this arrangement.

Comment: **@RobertPitt;** That is essentially what I am (*intend on*) doing. The `PageController` says "Gimme the user list" to the `Gateway`. The `Gateway` says "Yay" or "Nay" based on auth. If "Yay", it forwards the method call to the proposed `Model`, and said method validates and returns a data-set, which the `Controller` culminates and sends to the `View` for rendering. API calls are the same thing, except an `ApiController` rather than `PageController` and each method call is separately requested and sent through the `Gateway`, returned as JSON rather than to a `View`.

Comment: The issue I suppose, is that my page controllers don't represent entities in any way. There is no `User_Controller` alongside a `User_Model` in my approach. Page controllers are more abstract than that, representing the intent of the view, rather than the associated model.

Comment: There is this thing called View Model, which can be different from Domain Model

Comment: Readworthy and maybe related to parts of your question: ["... MVC as it was originally conceived about twenty years ago doesn't actually work on the web."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework/1549970#1549970)

Comment: **@driushkin & mario;** Thanks guys, good reads on both counts. The ViewModel in MVVM appears to share some architectural similarities with my implementation, in that with the inclusion of Controllers, it's simply adding/replacing another level of abstraction between the layers of MVC. As for approaching MVC with strict adherence, I don't believe I'm "*trying to fit a square peg into a round hole*", as described in the SO response, but I'm using the ideology of MVC as it relates to separation of concerns. Just how much separation, and in what way, is my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's just semantics but I would say that *The Model* is the representation of the the data, the classes (and by extension the objects) that encapsulate the entities in your application.  There's another, missing piece, which I would call the persistence or data access layer (DAL).  MVC as an abstraction doesn't really concern itself with persistence because you don't actually have to have persistence to develop using the MVC pattern.  In (almost?) all web applications using MVC, you **do** have a database and thus do need a persistence layer.  The persistence layer understands *The Model* and makes it available to the controller, but it's not really part of the model.

If you separate out the concepts of inserting/retrieving/updating the data into the persistence layer, what you're left with are the containers and associated business/validation logic that encapsulate the representation of your applications entities.  These should be relatively small, well-focused, and only interdependent on the actual data dependencies between your entities.  This small models, one per entity, in total comprise *The Model* for your application.  Your persistence layer (DAL/ORM), too, is not particularly large, but rather is focuses solely on interacting with the database to obtain/store the models.

Comment: **Thanks tvanfosson;** To clarify for my understanding, the persistence layer in this situation, would refer to a layer between the Controllers and Models that aggregates Model functionality into a (for lack of better terminology) query-able entity, representative of the application state (the Models themselves) In another sense my application layers could be described as; View-ViewController-ModelController-Model, with both the View and Model receiving a level of abstraction glue.

Comment: @Tomcat - I'm not sure I understand your description, but I would say that the controllers use the persistence layer to store/retrieve the domain models, yes.  The way I would describe MVC for the web is that the controllers respond to and interpret HTTP requests.  They get the relevant domain models from the persistence medium, often transforming them into view-specific models which may contain more or less data than the domain models.  They select a view to render and hand the view model off to it.  The view renders the data into the HTML response which is sent back to the client.

Comment: ... and I'll note that I've omitted some of the *guts* of the infrastructure for simplicity: routing engines, rendering engines, model binders, etc.

Comment: **@tvanfosson;** Having read a bit since I posted the comment, I realize the error in my explanation and understanding. I suppose the *main* issue I'm experiencing, in trying to tie this all together, is that my application architecture doesn't explicitly use CoC (Convention-over-Configuration) which is pivotal in many MVC frameworks and architectures. There is no relationship between `server.com/user/add` and the `User` data. The controllers "represent the intent of the view", rather than the model. Though, CoC is present in my application, as a means of using PHP magic for controller names.

Comment: ... because of the lack of CoC, the Controller/Model relationship has no implicitly defined functionality. I'm trying to find a nice, clean implementation of a naming-convention-agnostic data-layer for use as the 'M' in MVC the way it's seen in web application development. In fact, one could take the VC out altogether. I'm looking for an RPC-API layer friendly way of managing data.

Comment: ... I keep coming back to the idea of a class or some such library, which is just a wall of methods (`getUserById()`, `addPost()`, `eatGrilledCheeseSandwich()`, and so forth) but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @tomcat - the abstraction you're looking for is The Repository pattern, http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-8 (here for php) and http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html (the original).

Comment: **@tvanfossom;** Awesome. Cursory read says nail on the head. I'll learn and return, but accept in the meantime. Thank you sir. Perhaps drop those links in your answer for completeness and Google searchery help for others.