# Using two different directories for same namespace in Zend Framework 2 - howto?

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2, propel, autoload

I have ZF2 module, and simultaneously I use Propel genereted models hosted in `root-directory/generated-classes`. Can I make them share selfsame namespace - like `Bookstore` or so?

From `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader` I see:

```
public function registerNamespace($namespace, $directory)
{
    $namespace = rtrim($namespace, self::NS_SEPARATOR) . self::NS_SEPARATOR;
    $this->namespaces[$namespace] = $this->normalizeDirectory($directory);
    return $this;
}
```

so if I provide two directories in `Module.php`, the last will prevail.

There is also:

```
public function setFallbackAutoloader($flag)
{
    $this->fallbackAutoloaderFlag = (bool) $flag;
    return $this;
}
```

Can I resort to it and how do I leverage this option? Any other (better) options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't put my models directly in `/your-application/root`. This will be against ZF2's recommended directory scaffolding. Instead of that, I'd create a `/FooModule/src/FooModule/Model` directory and put all of my models inside this folder using `namespace FooModule\Model` namespace definition in model class.

Another detail is; trying to pointing two different directories for same namespace is absolutely bad idea. This will be against [PSR-4 Autoloading Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and lot of open source libraries & frameworks including Zend Framework 2 which heavily depends on this standard.

I would look at the problem from a different angle. Just ask: Why I need to point one of my namespaces to the two different directories?

I think actually you mean **Domain Entities** by "Propel generated models". If this is correct (i mean `Bookstore`) is an [Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) rather than a Model. You may also want to read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030030/199593).

So, you can try to create an `Entity` namespace in your `Application` (or whatever) ZF2 module and write your Entity classes under a sub-namespace inside that. This is perfectly valid. For example:

```
Application\src\Entity\Bookstore.php - namespace is Application\Entity
Application\src\Entity\Book.php - namespace is Application\Entity
Application\src\Entity\Author.php - namespace is Application\Entity
```

Or this is also valid scenario too (Bookstore is a module):

```
Bookstore\src\Entity\Book.php - namespace is Bookstore\Entity
Bookstore\src\Entity\Author.php - namespace is Bookstore\Entity
```

In both example scenarios, `Book.php` and `Author.php` are your *auto-generated domain entities* and they shares same namespace while not conflicting ZF2 or PSR-4 autoloading mechanisms.

Comment: **thnx!**

I am using Propel for a very few time, so after failing to find any config options to change destination folder for output, I decided kind of "symlink" generated-classes into ZF2 directory scaffolding via autoloading "black magic". Which was erroneus by far. Fortunately, there is awesome  `[--output-dir="..."]` option supported by command line `propel model:build`

Comment: btw, ZF2 supports multiple namespaces for a module, thus - should'nt it be Application/src/**Application**/Entity/Book.php and Bookstore/src/**Bookstore**/Entity/Book.php respectively?